# insert double rows in same form in laravel

Tags: php, mysql, laravel

I get nothing with inserting 2 rows at the same form using foreach loop

Her's the form :

```
  <form action="/adminPanel/products/store" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data" class="form-horizontal form-label-left" id="demo-form2">

 {{ csrf_field() }}

                  <div class="form-group">
        {!!Form::label("Product Title", null, ['class' => 'control-label col-md-3 col-sm-3 col-xs-12']) !!}

                    <div class="col-md-6 col-sm-6 col-xs-12">
        {!!Form::text('title[]'," ",["class"=>"form-control col-md-7 col-xs-12" ,"id"=>"last-name"])!!} 

                    </div>
                  </div>
                   <div class="form-group">
        {!!Form::label("Product Language", null, ['class' => 'control-label col-md-3 col-sm-3 col-xs-12']) !!}

                    <div class="col-md-6 col-sm-6 col-xs-12">

        <input type="text" name="language[]"  value="en" disabled>.

                    </div>
                  </div>
         <div class="form-group">
        {!!Form::label("Product Content", null, ['class' => 'control-label col-md-3 col-sm-3 col-xs-12']) !!}
                    <div class="col-md-6 col-sm-6 col-xs-12">
      <textarea class="form-control" rows="3"  name="content"></textarea>
                    </div>
                  </div>
         <div class="form-group">
        {!!Form::label("Product Price", null, ['class' => 'control-label col-md-3 col-sm-3 col-xs-12']) !!}
                    <div class="col-md-6 col-sm-6 col-xs-12">
        {!!Form::text('price[]'," ",["class"=>"form-control col-md-7 col-xs-12" ,"id"=>"last-name"])!!} 
                    </div>
                  </div>
                  <div class="form-group">
                {!!Form::label("Description Title", null, ['class' => 'control-label col-md-3 col-sm-3 col-xs-12']) !!}
                    <div class="col-md-6 col-sm-6 col-xs-12">
        {!!Form::text('description_title[]'," ",["class"=>"form-control col-md-7 col-xs-12" ,"id"=>"last-name"])!!} 
                    </div>
                  </div>

                   <div class="form-group">
        {!!Form::label("The Product Description", null, ['class' => 'control-label col-md-3 col-sm-3 col-xs-12']) !!}
                    <div class="col-md-6 col-sm-6 col-xs-12">
      <textarea class="form-control" rows="3"  name="description[]"></textarea>
                    </div>
                  </div>

                   <div class="form-group">
                {!!Form::label("The Product Info Title", null, ['class' => 'control-label col-md-3 col-sm-3 col-xs-12']) !!}
                    <div class="col-md-6 col-sm-6 col-xs-12">
      {!!Form::text('prod_info_title[]'," ",["class"=>"form-control col-md-7 col-xs-12" ,"id"=>"last-name"])!!} 
                    </div>
                  </div>

                   <div class="form-group">
        {!!Form::label("The Product Info", null, ['class' => 'control-label col-md-3 col-sm-3 col-xs-12']) !!}
                    <div class="col-md-6 col-sm-6 col-xs-12">
      <textarea class="form-control" rows="3"  name="prod_info[]"></textarea>
                    </div>
                  </div>

              <div class="form-group">
                    {!!Form::label("Main Product Image", null, ['class' => 'control-label col-md-3 col-sm-3 col-xs-12']) !!}
                    <div class="col-md-6 col-sm-6 col-xs-12">

                              <div class="form-group">
        {!!Form::label("Product Title", null, ['class' => 'control-label col-md-3 col-sm-3 col-xs-12']) !!}

                    <div class="col-md-6 col-sm-6 col-xs-12">
        {!!Form::text('title[]'," ",["class"=>"form-control col-md-7 col-xs-12" ,"id"=>"last-name"])!!} 

                    </div>
                  </div>
                   <div class="form-group">
        {!!Form::label("Product Language", null, ['class' => 'control-label col-md-3 col-sm-3 col-xs-12']) !!}

                    <div class="col-md-6 col-sm-6 col-xs-12">

        <input type="text" name="language[]"  value="ar" disabled>.

                    </div>
                  </div>
         <div class="form-group">
        {!!Form::label("Product Content", null, ['class' => 'control-label col-md-3 col-sm-3 col-xs-12']) !!}
                    <div class="col-md-6 col-sm-6 col-xs-12">
      <textarea class="form-control" rows="3"  name="content"></textarea>
                    </div>
                  </div>
         <div class="form-group">
        {!!Form::label("Product Price", null, ['class' => 'control-label col-md-3 col-sm-3 col-xs-12']) !!}
                    <div class="col-md-6 col-sm-6 col-xs-12">
        {!!Form::text('price[]'," ",["class"=>"form-control col-md-7 col-xs-12" ,"id"=>"last-name"])!!} 
                    </div>
                  </div>
                  <div class="form-group">
                {!!Form::label("Description Title", null, ['class' => 'control-label col-md-3 col-sm-3 col-xs-12']) !!}
                    <div class="col-md-6 col-sm-6 col-xs-12">
        {!!Form::text('description_title[]'," ",["class"=>"form-control col-md-7 col-xs-12" ,"id"=>"last-name"])!!} 
                    </div>
                  </div>

                   <div class="form-group">
        {!!Form::label("The Product Description", null, ['class' => 'control-label col-md-3 col-sm-3 col-xs-12']) !!}
                    <div class="col-md-6 col-sm-6 col-xs-12">
      <textarea class="form-control" rows="3"  name="description[]"></textarea>
                    </div>
                  </div>

                   <div class="form-group">
                {!!Form::label("The Product Info Title", null, ['class' => 'control-label col-md-3 col-sm-3 col-xs-12']) !!}
                    <div class="col-md-6 col-sm-6 col-xs-12">
      {!!Form::text('prod_info_title[]'," ",["class"=>"form-control col-md-7 col-xs-12" ,"id"=>"last-name"])!!} 
                    </div>
                  </div>

                   <div class="form-group">
        {!!Form::label("The Product Info", null, ['class' => 'control-label col-md-3 col-sm-3 col-xs-12']) !!}
                    <div class="col-md-6 col-sm-6 col-xs-12">
      <textarea class="form-control" rows="3"  name="prod_info[]"></textarea>
                    </div>
                  </div>
```

and here's the controller :

```
 if (isset($_POST['submit'])) {
            $parentproduct = new Product();
             $parentproduct->id = Input::get('id');
            $parentproduct->save();
            $insertedId = $parentproduct->id;
            $input = Input::all();
        for ($idx = 0; $idx < count(Input::get('language')); $idx++){

            $product = new ProductsTranslation();   
            $product->product_id = $insertedId;
            $product->title = $input['title'][$idx];
            $product->content = $input['content'][$idx];
            $product->price = $input['price'][$idx]; 
            $product->description_title = $input['description_title'][$idx];
            $product->prod_info_title = $input['prod_info_title'][$idx];
             $product->prod_info = $input['language'][$idx];
            $product->prod_info = $input['prod_info'][$idx];
            $product->save();

        }
```

The result with me nothing error or even add anything to my database !! can any one help please?

Comment: `if (isset($_POST['submit'])) {` in Laravel? You have to be kidding me…

Comment: Sorry it was a mistake , but that's not the error comes from